# Android drag and drop - cancel drag animation

Tags: android, view, drag-and-drop

I am developing a Chess application. I am struggling with implementing a proper drag/touch functionality. I am trying to achieve that with standard Android drag and drop using View.startDragAndDrop method. Unfortunatelly, I don't know how to properly handle cancel animation - the animation played when the drag and drop is cancelled. Is it achievable by Android framework?

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend finding better solution all together. Drag and drop is intended to carry snippets of data - possibly even between applications. It has awful performance and it's customization is very limited because it needs to go all the way up to and back from system layer.